# How are ItemContainerTemplates used when populating a menu?

Tags: wpf, menu, datatemplate

I recently spent far too long trying to figure out how to use the ItemContainerTemplate and the UsesItemContainerTemplate property on a menu.

Basically my problem was that no matter what I did, it seemed, it did not pick up on the templates.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SeparatorViewModel}">
            <Separator />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:ActionItemViewModel}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Caption}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

It would just use MenuItem as the container always.

But why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution of course is painfully simple. The MenuItem template must also have its UsesItemContainerTemplate property set to true.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SeparatorViewModel}">
            <Separator />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:ActionItemViewModel}">
            <MenuItem **UsesItemContainerTemplate="True"** Header="{Binding Path=Caption}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

I hope this can save others from spending time pulling at their possibly already receding hairline.

By the way I was unable to tag this properly with 'ItemContainerTemplate' and 'UsesItemContainerTemplate' since my reputation apparently is too low, so if anyone can do that, that would be great.

Adios.

Comment: I assume that adding UseItemContainerTemplate only applies when you have subitems, right?